# Setting Variables within `self.included`

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, why can't I set the value of variables *directly* within a module's `self.included` method?

For example, the following code outputs `NilClass` (indicating that the `@sound` variable has NOT been set):

```
module Animal
  def self.included(klass)
    attr_accessor :sound
    @sound = "Woof!" # <-- Variable assignment
  end

  def speak
    puts @sound.class
  end
end

class Dog
  include Animal
end

dog = Dog.new
dog.speak # => NilClass
```

However, if I set the value of `@sound` within the module's `speak` method (instead of inside of `self.included`), then the variable is set correctly. For example, the following code outputs `String`:

```
module Animal
  def self.included(klass)
    attr_accessor :sound
  end

  def speak
    @sound = "Woof!" # <-- Variable assignment
    puts @sound.class
  end
end

class Dog
  include Animal
end

dog = Dog.new
dog.speak # => String
```

I would have expected both code samples above to output `String`.

Comment: It makes a little more sense if you think about it from another perspective: which `Dog`'s `@sound` is included supposed to set? All of them? Are you really trying to initialize a default value for `Dog`s whose `@sound`s haven't already been set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first  example the receiver in `self.included` block is `Dog` class, not it's instance, meaning you are defining ***class instance variable*** `@sound`, not instance variable.

You can check it by running

```
Dog.instance_variable_get(:@sound) # with first example
```

`speak` method returns `NilClass` because `dog` does not have `@sound` instance variable defined.

In second example you are defining an ***instance variable*** `@sound`, thus it works as you expect.

Comment: Ah! This makes much more sense now. Thanks! In case anyone cares, based on this answer, I re-wrote my code as such: http://paste.ofcode.org/mkAEyhmPWANfthk2E9rY66